# How to pass command-line arguments in CTest at runtime?

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I would like to pass parameters to our Catch2 tests via ctest when running through bamboo or jenkins so that they product junit test results. So I would like to do something like:

```
make test ARGS="-r junit -o test_results.xml"
```

That would forward these on to my test:

```
unittest -r junit -o test_results.xml
```

That way when I run `make tests` it just runs the tests normally which pretty prints results to the console.

I know args can be added in the add_test() command but I'm looking for something more dynamic.

I'm hoping there is a way to do this in modern CMake.

Comment: link to the "similar question"?

Comment: Why not set an environment variable and read it in CMake, write it to `add_test()` (or `catch_discover_tests()` `EXTRA_ARGS`)?